# How to use recursive_update

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I just started to use DBx::Class and begun slightly to understand, but it's complex.

I want to call "recursive_update" but I was not able to manage how I can use it.

If I understand the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet::RecursiveUpdate) right, I have to include it in the .../My/Schema.pm which was create by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader?

```
__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces(default_resultset_class => '+DBIx::Class::ResultSet::RecursiveUpdate');
```

When I want to update the data I use the ResultSet with the relationships.

```
my $result = $schema->resultset('Table')->find($id});
$result->recursive_update({
            'rel_table' => [....),
});
```

unfortunately I got an error:

```
Can't locate object method "recursive_update" via package My::Schema::Result::Table"
```

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recursive_update` has to be called on a ResultSet object, not a Result object.

You might want to add a helper method to your Result base class (if you already have one else create it, as it makes sense for many things) which gets a ResultSet restricted to the Result object it is called on and calls `recursive_update` on it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. yes, I have a helper method with access at the ResultSet. There I can call recursive_update. But it seems I did misunderstood the function. I can't update the complete dataset itself, only the relations?

Comment: You can update the complete ResultSet including multiple rows (what becomes a Result object in DBIx::Class). One use-case is a ResultSet which only includes one specific Result.